# Mocking Interface Events Error

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to mock an interface's events like the following:

```
[TestMethod]
public void NeedingDataFiresEvents()
{
    //Arrange
    var service = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IService>();
    service.Expect(i => i.GetValue()).Return(5);
    var view = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ILogView>();
    view.NeedData += null;
    LastCall.IgnoreArguments();
    var evt = LastCall.GetEventRaiser();

    var presenter = new LogPresenter(view, service);
    var args = new DataEventArgs();

    //Act
    evt.Raise(view, args);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(1, args.Results.Count());
}
```

The error I'm getting is:
System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid call, the last call has been used or no call has been made (make sure that you are calling a virtual (C#) / Overridable (VB) method).

I'm not sure why... what am I doing wrong?  What would I apply virtual too, if I'm not actually instantiating the view...  Something in the presenter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured it out, this was the answer, to use the MockRepository instance ([an example, sample below taken from there](http://chakkaradeep.wordpress.com/category/mock-objects/)):

```
var fooDatabaseMock = new MockRepository();
var fooDatabase = fooDatabaseMock.DynamicMock<IFooDatabase>();
fooDatabase.FooDatabaseInsertEvent += null;

LastCall.IgnoreArguments();

var fooEventRaiser = LastCall.GetEventRaiser();
```

Comment: so you have completely changed based on the given link. Why i asked is to understand the size of fix

Comment: Instead of MockRepository.GenerateMock, I simply instantiated the MockRepository class, and used DynamicMock (I believe, it was a while ago).  So not too hard

Comment: thanks!. For me it was another issue like i was trying to mock a class instead of an interface. :(